# Is there a way to control the Perl Tk::TopLevel resize behavior?

Tags: perl

I am building Perl Tk application.

The main window of the application contains many widgets organized with `pack` geometry manager.

When the user resize the `TopLevel` window (moving the bottom/right corner with a mouse) the `TopLevel` widgets are constantly re-drawn. This cause a very "not-nice" window re-size behavior.

Is there a way to block `TopLevel` redraw behavior until the user release the mouse button? (and only then re-draw the widgets according to the new size?)

I checked the Perl `Tk:Wm`, `Tk:TopLevel` documents and didn't find any relevant info.

Comment: I am not sure how to instruct the geometry managers in Tk not to redraw during resize. Maybe you need to communicate directly with the underlying window manager? There is an example of using `withdraw()` in chapter 11.2 in the Perl Tk book. But I cannot see how to apply it since the `<Configure>` event seems to block `<ButtonPress>` and `<ButtonRelease>` events. So there is no way to determine when resizing is done. But it should be possible to achieve somehow..

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and the Unity window manager can do this, see [How to turn off window refreshing during resizing](http://askubuntu.com/questions/515827/how-to-turn-off-window-refreshing-during-resizing).